# TestNG ERROR Cannot find class in classpath: from CMD

Tags: testng

When running: -

```
java -cp C:\Air-Automatic-Testing-MVN\smokeTest\bin;C:\Air-Automatic-Testing-MVN\smokeTest\lib\* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

I get the error:-

[TestNG] [ERROR]
Cannot find class in classpath: smokeTest.AppTest

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something as I don't have a bin directory.  I created the lib directory, but I don't know what creates the bin.  My testing.xml runs within eclipse ok.

Any ideas?